# Encrypt/decrypt password and use it by ksh script

Tags: shell, scripting, openssl, ksh, password-encryption

I work on a RedHat linux server with an applicative user (no root).
I have a ksh script that make some `sqlplus` connections on different DBs by this command:

> `sqlplus -s myuser/password@DBNAME`.

This connections need passwords, each one different from the others.

I would like to encrypt these passwords and store them inside a file.
Then, each time i run my script it has to read a specific encrypted password, decryp it and finally pass it to `sqlplus` command.

About taking a specific passwd I suppose I can insert a label at the beginning of line but my question is how to encrypt this passwords with openSSL (I can't install any tool on the machine) and if it is a secure method to avoid plain text password sending. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's sort of a catch-22. If you want the script to verify a password that the user is providing you could use some hashing, like with htpasswd. But if you want the script to "know" the password to run unattended, that's another story. You can encode the password, Base64 by example, and decode on the fly. Granted the password won't be in clear text in a file but anyone with access would be able to decode. Same with encryption since the script will need to know the key to decrypt. Might as well use a hidden file with mode 600 and source it (that's what I do actually) in your script.

Comment: The file containing the encryped password would be placed into a "trusted" directory that nobody can access (except a particular user). For this reason I had thought this method.

Comment: Then use a hidden file (mode 600) with an associative array indexed with the UID and source that file. You would save the decryption overhead and have basically the same security.

Comment: Ok, I will try to do this. I don't know in practical what i have to do but i will do it. :)
Thanks.

Comment: I know about associative array and hidden file, but not really understand about

> **"...indexed with the UID and source that file."**

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

Credential file

```
#!/bin/ksh
#######################################################
#
# Source for UID/Password. MUST be with access 600
#
# .credential.sh
#
# Usage : . .credential.sh
#
######################################################

#Declaring associative array

typeset -A Password

# Setting the values

Password[USER1]="Passwd1"
Password[USER2]="Passwd2"
```

And in your script :

```
#!/bin/ksh

#sourcing the credential files
. /foo/bar/.credential.sh

#............... Some code
myuser=USER1 # Or whatever means to set the user variable
#............... Some code

sqlplus -s $myuser/${Password[$myuser]}@DBNAME

#............... Some code
```

Comment: Ok, perfect. Thanks a lot. About permissions, would be better to set them on 400 ? to avoid any possible modify. Do you agree or there's a specific reason to set on 600 ? Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't change much. With 400, you as the owner, will receive warning that the file is write protected if you try to edit or delete it, but with the option to override that protection. Also, an owner can always change the mode of its files.

Comment: Ok. Thank you.
Best reguards.